# Kendo autocomplete template from Image Data Type SQL Server

Tags: jquery, sql-server, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I need to show from images from database saved in image datatype in SQL Server, how I can do it?

```
<script>  
$("#txtCodigoInterno").kendoAutoComplete({
                dataTextField: "articulo",
                dataValueField: "cod_articulo",
                minLength: 3,
                clearButton: true,
                template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
                dataSource: srcArticulos,
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="txtCodigoInterno" placeholder="Buscar"  style="width: 750px; font-size:8pt;" class="k-textbox" />
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span>
        <img src="#:image #" alt="#: articulo #" />
        #: articulo #
    </span>
</script>
```

Comment: Slight detour....the image datatype has been deprecated in favor of varbinary(max) for more than a decade now. You might consider changing your table. Other than storing your data I don't really see how this is a sql server question though.

Comment: @SeanLange It is metter of an API question than SQL or JS/KendoUI in my opinion. The API will have to display a base64 encoded image or something like that in order to display it from database.